# java.lang.VerifyError: com/twitter/sdk/android/core/internal/SessionMonitor

Tags: java, android

When I initialize Fabric like this:

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```

App crashes with this error message:

> java.lang.VerifyError: com/twitter/sdk/android/core/internal/SessionMonitor

When I remove the twitter dependencies and fabric plugin from my build.gradle file my project works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error.Just fix it!!
I use Android studio. If you use the same IDE.
You could check Project->External Libraries .
Any libs exist two different version like this

My case：
There are two version support-v4-22.0.0 and  support-v4-22.2.1

You check *.iml to find where is different version
ex：

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-v4-22.0.0" level="project" />
```

When you find it . 
Edit build.gradle .

Add compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'

ex：

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'

}
```

Then it will be fixed.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Android Studio but i didn't find any duplicate library in External Libraries. And I also check my *.iml file, there is no duplicate entry for any library. Should I post any file content?